# How to send text and objects with on socket and still be able to use ready()

Tags: java, sockets, stream

I'm working on my MTG aplication and I encountered this problem:

I have two players playing against each other, there is one Thread working as server - there is infinite loop which waits if player 1 or 2 is trying to send something - for this I use bufferedReader with

```
if(inFromPlayer1.ready()){
....
}
```

Right now, players can only communicate with each other, but I also need to send cards between them, I tryed to make new

`ObjectInputStream(socket1.getInputStream())`

and read ArrayList from it, but when I do, I get Invalid Stream header exception. So, my question is: Is it possible to somehow make it work? Right now, I just need both, bufferedReader with ready check and objectreader for sending whole ArrayList of objects.

Comment: yes, it is possible to make it work (well, maybe).  without code, no one can help you make it work.  if you are trying to run a BufferedReader and ObjectInputStream on the same socket, then no, it won't work.  but, you can go with just the ObjectOutputStream and send messages as Strings

Comment: Yeah, but how can I check if there is something ready(without blocking if not) without bufferedreader? I tryed to test it with availible on oubjectStreamu but it didn't work.

Comment: You're asking the wrong question here. You should not use `ready()` or `available()`. They are not infallible. Your read thread should do blocking reads and nothing else.